# no attribute 'contrib' for problems()

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, tensor2tensor

I am trying to see the available problems() but it is giving Error.
Can you please let me know if I am missing anything

```
>>> from tensor2tensor import problems
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensor2tensor\problems.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensor2tensor.utils import registry
  File "C:\Users\\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensor2tensor\utils\registry.py", line 551, in <module>
    attacks = tf.contrib.framework.deprecated(None, "Use registry.attack")(attack)
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'contrib'
>>> tf.__version__
'2.0.0-beta1'
>>>
```

I am working on windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tensor2Tensor library [**is not yet compatible with Tensorflow 2.0**](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensor2tensor/issues/1524#issuecomment-476321189) because it still uses a lot of deprecated APIs. Your only option currently is to downgrade to an older version, such as Tensorflow 1.15.

```
pip3 install tensorflow==1.15.0
```